# Why PHP function is_link not recognizing link

Tags: php, symlink

It's simple to reproduce. Just create some folder, I named it `php-test`. And another folder, `target`. Then cd to `php-test` and

```
$ mkdir uploads
$ ln -sfn ../target uploads
```

Check if we have a symlink

```
$ ls -l uploads
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 travel travel 9 Apr 15 18:51 target -> ../target
```

Create test.php inside current dir:

```
<?php

$link = 'uploads';

if (is_link($link)) {
    echo "is link $link\n";
} else {
    echo "not a link $link\n";
}
```

And run it

```
$ php test.php
```

May somebody explain why the output is

```
not a link uploads
```

?

Comment: Where is the route of your project, can you run 
print_r(scandir('.'));

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link#refsect1-function.is-link-parameters) the parameter must be a file. As it says there: filename is path to the file.

```
touch filelink
ln -sfn ../target filelink
```

Be careful your path to the link is correct. Your test.php must be in the same php-test directory to work this way.

```
<?php

$link = 'filelink';

if (is_link($link)) {
    echo "is link $link\n";
} else {
    echo "not a link $link\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I really need to check if directory is a link. Probably have to post another question for this...